# PhpStorm browser button custom url

Tags: browser, phpstorm

Is it possible to change the url that the browser buttons in PhpStorm to go to a different url?

[image]

Currently these all take me to `localhost:63342/[project name]/`

I would like to direct these to a different address, `[projectname].serveraddress:1111/` for example.

Currently my workaround is to use a PHP Web Page configuration but this required me to pick a browser at configuration level rather than being able to pick and choose.

I have a server config setup to automatically upload the files on change already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just set up the Deployment entry and mark it as Default for this project.

- When you are using "Open in Browser" or similar functionality, IDE looks for your default deployment entry and builds the URL based on those rules (web server URL + mappings).
- If no default deployment entry is found then IDE builds URL for the built-in simple web server that uses `localhost:63342/[project name]/path/file.ext` URLs.

**P.S.** If it's a local server (files served directly from the original location) and no actual deployment is needed then use ["In-place"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/creating-in-place-server-configuration.html) type of config.